# Use CLI to Deploy Code to Existing Amazon EB Environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've created an AWS Elastic Beanstalk application and environment. However, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to deploy code to it. Most tutorials I read are for creating a new application directly from the CLI, but I already have one.

I've installed the AWS CLI tools. I created a SSH key-pair to the environment and added it to my .ssh folder. I created an IAM profile and logged in with that in my terminal.

If I understand correctly, I need to do `eb use [my environment name]` so I can then `eb deploy` to it. But when I use `eb list`, nothing comes up. How can I connect to the environment that already exists on AWS?

I am using Linux (WSL on Windows). I'm also on the Free Tier of AWS.

Comment: did you try to do 'eb init' inside the code folder?

Comment: Yes I tried that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use AWS CLI commands or EB CLI commands to deploy your applications.

1. Congfigure the source, GIT or S3. e.g. I have uploaded my_app.zip to my_bucket in S3.
2. Create a new application version. It is a good practise to use commit hash as version label.

```
aws elasticbeanstalk create-application-version
    --application-name <EB_APP_NAME> --version-label <version-label>
    --source-bundle S3Bucket="my_bucket",S3Key=my_app.zip --auto-create-application
```

3. Update the environment to point to the new application version. The value of version-label should be the same as in the previous step.

```
aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment
          --application-name <EB_APP_NAME>
          --environment-name <EB_ENV_NAME>
          --version-label <version-label>
```

The alternative way is to use EB CLI. `eb deploy` handles all 3 steps above.

1. Initialize EB CLI using [eb init](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-configuration.html).
2. Deploy using [eb deploy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-cli-git.html).

Comment: I want to be able to do it using the EB CLI. If I do `eb deploy` I get `ERROR: This branch does not have a default environment. You must either specify an environment by typing "eb deploy my-env-name" or set a default environment by typing "eb use my-env-name".` If I do `eb deploy [env name on AWS console]` it uploads to the right S3 bucket, but then says `ERROR: InvalidParameterValueError - No Environment found for EnvironmentName [same env name as before].`

Comment: Just make sure that your CLI is configured to use the same region in which your environment is created.